# Colorize fish -ls

Tags: macos, colors, ls, fish

How do I colorize the `ls` command in fish? I am using ITerm2 on Mac with appropriate fonts etc. For some reason it stopped working on my computer. When I do the recommended

```
 function ls
   command ls --color=auto $argv
 end
```

I get that the --color command is not recognized `ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]`

I thought it might be due to installing gnucoreutils and writing over fish's ls command, but removing it did not seem to help. When I do ls -G via alias, I can get colorized output for folders for a session, but it resets at end of session back to the original. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: have you tried to specify full path `/bin/ls` or to other local installation path  to be sure it's not due to PATH environment variable

Comment: It looks like you're using the standard OS X `ls` command, not the `gnu` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The */bin/ls* command on macOS has different options than the GNU Linux version. Replace `--color=auto` with `-G`. Alternatively, install the GNU version using Homebrew to install the "coreutils" package. Then invoke it as `gls`.